# Multikey map with Long or AtomicLong value in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, guava, atomic

I need a multikey map with `AtomicLong` value. So something which is like [AtomicLongMap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/util/concurrent/AtomicLongMap.html) of *guava* but one that supports multiple keys. So my new Map should be able to do like:

```
MultiKeyAtomicLongMap<String, String> map = ...

map.put("a", "A", 1L);
map.put("a", "B", 2L);
map.put("b", "C", 3L);
....
map.get("a", "A");  // This should give me value 1L
map.get("a");  // This should give me both mappings ["A", 1L] and ["B", 2L]
```

So the above code is just to explain the expected behavior, but not strictly what I want.

Essentially what I want is thread-safe multikey map where my both keys are `String` and value is `long`.

---

**EDIT:**
I am fine with keeping the value `Long` instead of `AtomicLong` but I just want the map to be *thread-safe*.

Comment: It looks more like you need a Guava `Table<String, String, AtomicLong>`, no?

Comment: @ControlAltDel It doesn't make easy retrieval of a single key (as is OPs second `get` requirement)

Comment: @JohnVint I think your first comment counts as  an answer...

Comment: @JohnVint Ah thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your answer @JohnVint.  The only issue I see here because of value being `AtomicLong` is to put a new mapping I have to do this:
            `AtomicLong atomicLong = table.get("a", "A");`
            `if (atomicLong == null) {`
                `atomicLong = new AtomicLong(0L);`
            `}`
            `atomicLong.incrementAndGet();`
            `table.put("a", "A", atomicLong);`
Is this fine?

Comment: @Learner that wouldn't be an `Atomic` use of `AtomicLong`. You only need to put the reference in the table if the table doesn't have it.

Comment: @James Yes, so what should be done to make it thread safe? using just `Long` and externally synchronize it, I don't that would be good too.

Comment: @Learner, that could make it thread safe though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is based on the comment by [Jon Vint](https://stackoverflow.com/users/192444/john-vint)

> It looks more like you need a Guava Table

Guava table looks like it gives you what you need, but there isn't currently a thread safe implementation. Part of the difficulty is that you need to manage a Map of Maps, and expose access to a Map of values.

But if you are happy to synchronize access to your own collection, I think a guava table can provide you with the functionality you want and you can add the thread safety. And add the utilities you want for inc/dec Long.

This is a little more abstract than you were asking, but I think this gives what you need:

```
import com.google.common.base.MoreObjects;
import com.google.common.collect.HashBasedTable;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;
import com.google.common.collect.Table;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import javax.annotation.concurrent.GuardedBy;

/**
 * Provide something like the {@link com.google.common.util.concurrent.AtomicLongMap} but supporting
 * multiple keys.
 *
 * Should be able to put a value using two keys. And retrieve either a precise cell. Or retrieve a
 * collection of values.
 *
 * Created by James on 28/02/2017.
 */
public class SynchronizedMultimap<Row, Column, Value> {

    private final Object mutex = new Object();
    @GuardedBy("mutex") // All read and write access to delegate must be protected by mutex.
    private final Table<Row, Column, Value> delegate = HashBasedTable.create();

    /**
     * {@link Table#put(Object, Object, Object)}
     * Associates the specified value with the specified keys. If the table
     * already contained a mapping for those keys, the old value is replaced with
     * the specified value.
     *
     * @return The old value associated with the keys or {@code null} if no previous value existed.
     */
    public Value put(Row row, Column column, Value value) {
        synchronized (mutex) {
            return delegate.put(row, column, value);
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@link java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap#computeIfAbsent(Object, Function)}
     *
     * Checks the existing value in the table delegate by {@link Table#get(Object, Object)} and
     * applies the given function, the function in this example should be able to handle a null input.
     *
     * @return The current value of the Table for keys, whether the function is applied or not.
     */
    public Value compute(Row row, Column column, Function<Value, Value> function) {
        synchronized (mutex) {
            Value oldValue = delegate.get(row, column);
            Value newValue = function.apply(oldValue);
            if (newValue != null) {
                delegate.put(row, column, newValue);
                return newValue;
            }
            return oldValue;
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@link Table#get(Object, Object)}
     *
     * @return The value associated with the keys or {@code null} if no value.
     */
    public Value get(Row row, Column column) {
        synchronized (mutex) {
            return delegate.get(row, column);
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@link Table#row(Object)}
     *
     * @return An immutable map view of the columns in the table.
     */
    public Map<Column, Value> get(Row row) {
        synchronized (mutex) {
            // Since we are exposing
            return ImmutableMap.copyOf(delegate.row(row));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // Even toString needs protection.
        synchronized (mutex) {
            return MoreObjects.toStringHelper(this)
                .add("delegate", delegate)
                .toString();
        }
    }
}
```

And for Long specific behaviours:

```
/**
 * Provides support for similar behaviour as AtomicLongMap.
 *
 * Created by James on 28/02/2017.
 */
public class SynchronizedLongMultimap<Row, Column> extends SynchronizedMultimap<Row, Column, Long> {

    /**
     * @return Adds delta to the current value and returns the new value. Or delta if no previous value.
     */
    public long addAndGet(Row row, Column column, long delta) {
        return compute(row, column,
            (Long oldValue) -> (oldValue == null) ? delta : oldValue + delta);
    }

    /**
     * @return Increments the current value and returns the new value. Or 1 if no previous value.
     */
    public long increment(Row row, Column column) {
        return compute(row, column, (Long oldValue) -> (oldValue == null) ? 1 : oldValue + 1);
    }

    /**
     * @return Decrements the current value and returns the new value. Or -1 if no previous value.
     */
    public long decrement(Row row, Column column) {
        return compute(row, column, (Long oldValue) -> (oldValue == null) ? -1 : oldValue - 1);
    }
}
```

Added unit tests to show the logic

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.core.IsEqual.equalTo;

import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;
import org.junit.Test;

/**
 * Test simple functionality of the Map is sound.
 *
 * Created by James on 28/02/2017.
 */
public class SynchronizedLongMultimapTest {

    private final SynchronizedLongMultimap<String, String> map = new SynchronizedLongMultimap<>();

    @Test
    public void addAndGet_SingleCell() {
        // add and get sets the initial value to the delta
        assertThat(map.addAndGet("0", "0", 1), equalTo(1L));
        assertThat(map.addAndGet("0", "0", 1), equalTo(2L));
        assertThat(map.addAndGet("0", "0", 0), equalTo(2L));
        assertThat(map.addAndGet("0", "0", -2), equalTo(0L));
    }
    @Test
    public void addAndGet_RangeCells() {
        // add and get sets the initial value to the delta
        assertThat(map.addAndGet("0", "1", 123), equalTo(123L));

        // add and get sets the initial value to the delta
        assertThat(map.addAndGet("1", "1", 42), equalTo(42L));
        // add and get adds the delta to the existing value
        assertThat(map.addAndGet("1", "1", -42), equalTo(0L));
    }

    @Test
    public void increment() {
        // increment sets the initial value to one
        assertThat(map.increment("0", "0"), equalTo(1L));
        // then adds one each time it's called
        assertThat(map.increment("0", "0"), equalTo(2L));
    }

    @Test
    public void decrement(){
        // decrement sets the initial value to -1 if no previous value
        assertThat(map.decrement("apples", "bananas"), equalTo(-1L));
        // then decrements that
        assertThat(map.decrement("apples", "bananas"), equalTo(-2L));
    }

    @Test
    public void get_PreviousValueIsNull() {
        assertThat(map.get("toast", "bananas"), equalTo(null));
        // even if we ask again
        assertThat(map.get("toast", "bananas"), equalTo(null));
    }

    @Test
    public void get_ProvidedByPut() {
        assertThat(map.put("toast", "corn flakes", 17L), equalTo(null));
        // then we get what we put in
        assertThat(map.get("toast", "corn flakes"), equalTo(17L));
    }

    @Test
    public void get_ColumnMap() {
        // Expected behaviour from MultiKeyMap question
        assertThat(map.put("a", "A", 1L), equalTo(null));
        assertThat(map.put("a", "B", 2L), equalTo(null));
        assertThat(map.put("b", "C", 3L), equalTo(null));

        // then we can get a single value
        assertThat(map.get("a", "A"), equalTo(1L));
        // or a Map
        assertThat(map.get("a"), equalTo(ImmutableMap.of("A", 1L, "B", 2L)));
        // even if that Map only has a single value
        assertThat(map.get("b"), equalTo(ImmutableMap.of("C", 3L)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just wondering does the get methods `Map<Column, Value> get(Row row) ` and `Value get(Row row, Column column)` also have to be synchronized? Or since they are read operations can they be lock free?

Comment: @Learner yes they need to be synchronized in this example otherwise the results would be nondeterministic. They could be guarded another way, using a `ReadWriteLock` instead of the synchronized blocks.

Comment: +1 thanks @James, you mean using `ReadWriteLock` only for get/read operations and write operations using the synchronization you showed in the code?

Comment: Hi @Learner, you need to be careful when picking your concurrency strategy, as it can lead to much confusion and strange results to mix approaches.

Answer (score 3):

You may use [Tables.synchronizedTable(Table table)](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Tables.html#synchronizedTable-com.google.common.collect.Table-) with `Long` value. This will give you thread safe implementation of *guava* `Table` like following:

```
Table<R, C, V> table = Tables.synchronizedTable(HashBasedTable.<R, C, V>create());
 ...
 Map<C, V> row = table.row(rowKey);  // Needn't be in synchronized block
 ...
 synchronized (table) {  // Synchronizing on table, not row!
   Iterator<Map.Entry<C, V>> i = row.entrySet().iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
   while (i.hasNext()) {
     foo(i.next());
   }
 }
```

**Note:** Do not miss on the important advice that *user needs to manually synchronize on the returned table when accessing any of its collection views* because those collection views returned by `Table` methods are not synchronized.

Comment: Good answer @kuldeep-jain but that's only available in a snapshot build of Guava.

Comment: +1 Wow, this is nice, I wish it was released. Do we have the dates when guava 22.0 version will be released? I could not find that.

Comment: Yes, this is available in 22.0-SNAPSHOT version. I am not sure when that would be released though. I think for now, you could go ahead with the approach which @James suggested in his answer.

Comment: I don't think it will be far away